# Nested theorems in Coq

Tags: coq

Is it possible to create a nested theorems in context of currently proving theorem?

I have a strong feeling that this feature is not fully implemented yet. 
For examples,

1) I can't destruct some of the types which were in the context during the proof process.

For example there is

```
"Error: my_var is used in conclusion."
```

when I am trying to define type of the theorem. I have also

```
"Error: ... depends on the variable ... which is not declared in the context."
```

But google gave me only one link with similar error. Moreover I actually have the m in the Context in this section. What's wrong?

2) I destructed natural number n.
   I defined several first steps.
   I need to define a synonym for long term.
   I want to locally define

```
Definition X:=(n.+1;ob).
```

But I can not. I want to use analogue to let ... in ... .

Any ideas?

Comment: For the 2nd part: `remember (<some long term>) as X` might work.

Comment: For the first part you may use `assert (H: forall n, n+n=2*n).` and start to prove it, and can then use `H` in your proof. It is not declared on the global context, only in the particular sub-goal you are working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed you are right. "declaring a theorem while in a proof" is not supported by Coq, due to some particularities with side effects.

Even if the feature works some times, it is considered to be broken. The only reason it has not been deleted is that some users got used to relying on it, and it is useful when it works. But there has been a lot of discussion on whether to fix it or remove it.